# warning: already initialized

Tags: ruby, warnings, constants

I'm new to coding in ruby and I am wondering why I get a warning when running the code below.

I checked a few answers to similar questions but can't seem to make it work for me.

Would you know why this happening and how to fix it?

Thank you so much!

Here is the warning I get in the terminal

```
test_Amazon.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant PAGE_URL
test_Amazon.rb:9: warning: previous definition of PAGE_URL was here
```

Here is the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'



for $i in (1..5)

PAGE_URL = "http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers/zgbs/automotive/?pg=#$i"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))

    page.css(".zg_itemWrapper").each do |item|  
        price = item.at_css(".zg_price .price").text
        asin =  item.at_css(".zg_title a")[:href].split("/")[5].chomp
        product_name = item.at_css(".zg_title a")[:href].split("/")[3]

        puts "#{asin} #{price} #{product_name}"

    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uppercase variables are in fact constants. You get this warning when you change the value of a constant. To avoid this warning in your example use a local variable instead of a constant to store the URL:

```
5.times do |i|
  page_url = "http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers/zgbs/automotive/?pg=#{i+1}"
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page_url))

  page.css(".zg_itemWrapper").each do |item|  
    ...
  end
end
```

Another thing you should avoid is global variables like `$i`. There is almost never a reason to have a variable that is globally accessible in your whole codebase.

Comment: Thank you so much spickermann! I was able to get rid of the warning by making page_url lowercase. Is there any benefit to use ".times" vs  "for  in" ?

Comment: Yes, there is a benefit. `for ... in` pollutes the other namespace. Whereas the block variable in `times` (like `each` or `map`) isn't set anymore after the block ended. Therefore `for ... in` isn't used in Ruby. You might want to read [The Evils of the For Loop](http://graysoftinc.com/early-steps/the-evils-of-the-for-loop)